# Microsoft Pubcenter - AdUnits - best way to use?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

I have 12 different apps on WP7 platform and the trial versions use Microsoft Advertising to display ads.
Should I be creating an AdUnit for each app separately on PubCenter or should I create a single AdUnit and use it for all my apps.

Does this even matter?  I mean, if the apps have a single adunit, can it make more money (eCPM)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as off topic, I think it's a pretty good question. One thing to remember with ad units is that they can only have a limited number of categories available. A good approach is to create a variety of ad units with a range of categories and use some sort of web service for switching ad units in your apps. This avoids the need for resubmission and allows you to test different categories to maximise your eCPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An ad unit is the space on a webpage where ads are displayed. An ad unit can display one or more ads. You determine how you want an ad unit to look, where you want it to appear on a page, and what kind of ad content you'd like to see displayed. You can add different ad units to different pages on your website, or use a single ad unit for all webpages.

From: [Microsoft Pubcenter](http://adcenterhelp.microsoft.com/help.aspx?project=adcenter_pub_rtw_ss&market=en-us&querytype=topic&query=pub_conc_adunits.htm)

Comment: Mohib, thanks for the reply.  I am talking specifically about using an Ad Unit for Windows PHone 7 devices.  Should I be creating an ad unit specifically for each app or should I create one to use in all my apps? Which one will give me more monetization? Thanks again

Comment: I dont think either way is going to hamper monetization. Its totally cosmetic. An Ad Unit can be specific or generic depending how you want it to be displayed in your applications. If you want them to be same you can use a single Ad Unit. Also different Ad Units will come useful in tracking which application is giving you how many views.

Comment: You are welcome and goodluck with your apps.

Comment: Thanks Mohib. Check out all my apps at http://www.gotechark.com

Comment: I have done that. Your apps are doing great and you have been featured on AppHub as well. Great going. Let me know if you have any work for me :)

Comment: Mohib, Social Mints is now available in the marketplace.  check it out! What is the best way to reach you and what are you working on? Let's discuss.

Comment: My email & website are mentioned in my profile ;) Drop me a mail on how we can collaborate..